# Changing transparency of markers in Chimera X

Tags: visualization, 3d-structure, software-usage

I am using the software [Chimera X](https://www.rbvi.ucsf.edu/chimerax/) to visualize the 3d composition of molecules. I am very new to Chimera and only use it for visualization. The files I'm using are cmm files (xml-formatted) basically looking like below:

```xml
...
<marker id="14" x="0.018" y="-0.180" z="0.215" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="15" x="-0.032" y="-0.191" z="0.241" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="16" x="-0.033" y="-0.117" z="0.246" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="17" x="0.020" y="-0.138" z="0.244" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="18" x="0.047" y="-0.083" z="0.280" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="19" x="0.073" y="-0.061" z="0.240" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="20" x="0.010" y="-0.068" z="0.271" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
...
<link id1="0" id2="1" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="1" id2="2" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="2" id2="3" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="3" id2="4" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="4" id2="5" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
...
```

i.e. just a simple polymer consisting of alot of markers (spheres) and links between them (cylinders), and with colors for each one specified in rgb (see [here](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/markers.html)). This is all well and good, but now I would like to set transparency for a subset of the markers and associated links. Preferably I would set this directly in the attributes in the cmm files, but I cannot find how to do this. The manual does mention that colours in general can be set with rgba where a means alpha level, but when trying to set a like seen in the xml block above, nothing happens (I tried values close to both 0 and 1; no difference)

The manual documents a function called 'transparency' which I tried to use with for example `transparency 50,a #0:10-1200`
to make atoms 10-1200 50% transparent. But I just get the error: "Missing or invalid "percent" argument: Expected a number". If I only type `transparency 50` everything does turn transparent, however, I wouldn't really call it transparent since I cannot really see through them to see the other molecules on the other side, they just turn bleak.

Questions:

1. *(Would someone explain how I could simply change the actual transparency of a large set of markers and links)* (preferably by loading some file with specified marker id:s)? Also, is it possible to assign this directly in the cmm files, and if so, how?

UPDATE: The command `transparency #1:2492-end 90 'All'` worked to set the transparency of markers e.g. 2492-end. What I would still like to know is if it is possible to set this directly in the cmm-files.

Comment: RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha channel - which specifies the opacity for a color. An RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque). , what does the  a="0"  do in your xml formatted markers and links ?

Comment: So, the 'a="0"' was a naive attempt by me to set the alpha-level directly in the xml file, which as I noted above did not work. I have since figured out how to set the transparency and will update my question.

Comment: you should try to report the bug a = 0 not working to chimerax developers. To report a problem with ChimeraX:

    If possible, please use Help... Report a Bug in the ChimeraX menu. Otherwise (for example, if ChimeraX will not start), send e-mail to chimerax-bugs@cgl.ucsf.edu, making sure to include any information needed to reproduce the problem: program version, specific data, actions/steps taken, etc. The information will be publicly accessible, so do not include data or descriptions that you wish to remain private.
from https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/contact.html

Comment: I will look in to that, however I am not certain it is a bug: Even though it seems very reasonable to be able to set it that way, that was a guess on my part. The general support of rgba colors is however otherwise documented in the manual. Regarding your suggested edit: The markers are literally referred to as 'atoms' in Chimera, and it is those which I wish to make transparent. (I am however changing it to 'marker' as a compromise =).)

Comment: A marker is a pseudoatom, typically used to mark the position of some feature within volume data; markers are implemented as atoms, so actions that apply to atoms in ChimeraX also apply to markers: they can be specified in commands, selected, etc. https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/markers.html

Comment: dont know why I didnt like ChimeraX at the time , ages ago,  but haved worked only with just plain Chimera, had to dig an old VMwareVM to take these few pics

Comment: users mailing list is https://mail.cgl.ucsf.edu/mailman/mailman3/lists/chimera-users.cgl.ucsf.edu/ .. dont get why  a='50' or a='0.5' dont work with chimera too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not an answer, but to better visualize the problem I recreated the question/answer on `Chimera` that has a different syntax for the `transparency`  command see : https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/midas/transparency.html and https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/commands/transparency.html .

Input file is `marker.cmm` , to be opened in `FILE MENU` of `VOLUME TRACER` from `VOLUME MENU` :

```
<marker_set name="marker set 1">
<marker id="14" x="0.018" y="-0.180" z="0.215" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="15" x="-0.032" y="-0.191" z="0.241" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="16" x="-0.033" y="-0.117" z="0.246" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="17" x="0.020" y="-0.138" z="0.244" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="18" x="0.047" y="-0.083" z="0.280" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="19" x="0.073" y="-0.061" z="0.240" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<marker id="20" x="0.010" y="-0.068" z="0.271" r="1.000000" g="0.254900" b="0.050980" a="0" radius="0.018754" />
<link id1="14" id2="15" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="15" id2="16" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="17" id2="18" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="18" id2="19" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
<link id1="19" id2="20" r="0.800000" g="0.800000" b="0.000000" a="0" radius="0.006251"/>
</marker_set>
```

Image before command :

[image]

Image after `transparency  50,a,b #0:16-end`

(#0 being 0 model as the only loaded model on my `Chimera` instance) :

[image]

Better transparency visualizations :

[image]

[image]

Dont get why a='50' or a='0.5' in `marker`,`link` definition dont work with `chimera` too

Comment: Together with my edited question I think this all suffice as "good enough" for now at least. I am satisfied for the moment just using something like `transparency #1:2492-end 90 'All'`, but I guess when I get more complicated regions it would be good to be able to load the marker spec, i.e. e.g. #1:2492-2500, 3000-3500, ... from a file if that is possible. But I guess one can run command-files right? and I suppose there's no limit on the length on the spec, so perhaps I could just create one very long command in a file. (Many thanks for your efforts!!! unfortunately I need more rep to upvote)